# Calculate average based on terms in columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  device     date  output
0      a  2019-06       4
1      a  2019-07       9
2      b  2019-06       6
3      b  2019-07       4
4      b  2019-08       5
5      c  2019-06      14
6      d  2019-06      19
7      d  2019-07      22
```

I am trying to calculate the average of each device, I hope the result like this:

```
  device  average
0      a  6.5
1      b  3
2      c  14
3      d  20.5
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use group by to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with `'mean'`.

```py
dfg = df.groupby('device', as_index=False).agg({'output': 'mean'})

# display(dfg)
  device  output
0      a     6.5
1      b     5.0
2      c    14.0
3      d    20.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it -

```
df.groupby(['device'])['output'].mean()
```